# How to get rid of these marks?

Tags: keyboard, troubleshooting

[image: Android Keyboard]

I'm 100 percent sure that it's possible because I managed to do it a few months ago, but now I do not know (don't remember) how to do it again. It looks like someone can help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be in the keyboard settings, go to Settings -> Language and Input or similar.

Comment: It would help to know which keyboard app you are using (looks like [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin), but you can never be sure) and Android version on your device.

Comment: I'm using Android 6.0.

Comment: Matthew Read, your response isn't full, I knew about those settings, but I've not managed to find the settings allowing to change the appearance of the keyboard (I mean deleting these marks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by hiding the auto correction in android `Keyboard Settings` under `Settings`,

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Language Settings]

Else, Try as mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoG/comments/39g7ck/how_to_remove_this_punctuation_and_mic_bar_on_my/?).

Comment: Much obliged. It was helpful.